# NodeMCU TCP connection timeout

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying out the Elecrow ESP8266 and using the NodeMCU firmware (nodemcu_integer_0.9.6-dev_20150704.bin). My connection code looks like this:

```
function foo()
  conn = net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)      
  conn:on("connection", function() 
    text = "some text\r\n"
    conn:send(text)
  end)
  conn:connect(5000,"192.168.240.1")
end
```

This is in a function. My first question is when do we exit out of this function? Do I have to explicitly have an 'exit' statement? I realize NodeMCU is event-driven, and the call to connect is after the logic handling a 'connection' (at which point I send something). I'm ok with that but I wonder how and when we get out of 'foo'.

The other thing is, how do I implement a timeout on this? I'd want to timeout and exit when that occurs.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Why do you think, that you are not getting out of the `foo()` function?

Comment: Also 0.9.6 is old and buggy. Use a build from https://nodemcu-build.com/

Answer (score 1):

In this piece of code, between function foo() and end, you are defining the function foo () not executing it at this moment.

This code will be executed when this function is called in another code with a foo()

When you call foo () and the foo () code is executed, When you call foo () and the foo () code is executed, you first

```
conn = net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
```

create (in the present) a socket and assign it to the variable conn. conn is the soket from that moment.

Then,

```
conn:on("connection", function() 
  text = "some text\r\n"
  conn:send(text)
end)
```

you assign a callback function that will be executed in the (future) event when the socket achieves a connection.

Then,

```
conn:connect(5000,"192.168.240.1")
```

you ask the plug to try a connection and the execution of the function foo () ends (and foo () returns)

In an imaginary time line things could go like this.

When the interpreter reads the code [function foo() ... end], the function foo () is defined, but not executed.

0us   **foo()**     The foo() code starts executing because we call foo()

20us  **net.create...** The socket is created

40us  **conn:on...**        Certain callback function is asignated to de socket

60us  **conn:connect..**    The socket starts an attempt to connect

65 us                   The foo() function ends and returns, and "another code" is executed

120 us                  The socket achieves the connection and the callback function is triggered

125 us                  The callback code:

```
text = "some text\r\n"
conn:send(text)
```

is executed in parallel with "another code"

The future event "socket connected" fires, in the future, the callback asigned, in the present, with conn:on()